# How can we get full path of a .exe file, in a c program?

Tags: c

Here is the code I am working on. What changes are required for the program to automatically detect its exe file path and save it in a string variable?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<dir.h>

void main()
{

    int check;
    char dirname[150], u_name[30];

    printf("Enter a username:");
    scanf("%s",&u_name);

    strcpy(dirname,"C:/Users/Bilal/Desktop/");
    strcat(dirname,u_name);
    check = mkdir(dirname);

    if (!check)
    printf("Directory created\n");

    else
    {
        printf("Unable to create directory\n");
        exit(1);
    } 

    printf("\nPress any key to exit program");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: So, what is the issue? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Using `system()` and **horrible** `gets()`, you should have other problems first, but as your code is specifically Windows already, you could use [`GetModuleFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You need to look at the `argv` parameter for `main`. You are declaring `main()` but it actually takes arguments: `main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Check `argv[0]` for the path of the `.exe` file of your program.

Comment: I can't see a question here. You just state a goal.

Comment: Yikes, your code is rife with vulnerabilities.  Not only should your compiler be screaming at you to not use `gets()`, you have buffers declared with magic numbers and no length checking anywhere!

Comment: In addition to other comments, `<conio.h>` is non-standard, and `main()` returns `int` not `void` in standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will tell you where exe is running from.

```
#include <windows.h>
...
WCHAR dirname[1024];
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, dirname, 1024);
```

Convert `wchar_t` to `char` using [wcstombs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_wcstombs.htm).

```
strcat(dirname, whatever); // Or strncat
mkdir(dirname);
```

Comment: You'll have to strip the actual filename first!